# Write a program to load Item Manufacturer tab and print each row details in a text/csv file

Tags: oracle-agile-plm

im new to **oracle agile plm** can you solve me this.I refer **Agile sdk guide** but it not at all solving can you make this efficient search

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: If this is still unresolved, please state your request clearly. Whether you want parts to be loaded with manufacturer details from CSV or to write the current data from Agile PLM to a file?
Based on your answer we'll have inherency questions like is it for all the parts or selective? Or do you want to create manufacturer parts with or without rolling revision? etc..

Answer (score 0):

In many documentations, you may not find code samples of every feature that there is. Instead, you are provided with one sample code which can be used with little modification for similar scenarios. In this case, you have code sample for reading the BOM table as below:

```
 private void printBOM(IItem item, int level) throws APIException {
        ITable bom = item.getTable(ItemConstants.TABLE_BOM);
        Iterator i = bom.getReferentIterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            IItem bomItem = (IItem)i.next();
            System.out.print(indent(level));
            System.out.println(bomItem.getName());
            printBOM(bomItem, level + 1);
        }
    }
    private String indent(int level) {
        if (level <= 0) {
            return "";
        }
        char c[] = new char[level*2];
        Arrays.fill(c, ' ');
        return new String(c);
    }
```

All you need to do is change `TABLE_BOM` to `TABLE_MANUFACTURERS`, update relevant attribute names and fetch data from required cells.

Hope this helps.

Also, here's the link for latest documentation: [SDK Developer Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E83928_04/otn/pdf/integration/agaap.pdf)